# PostgreSQL: Foreign key between composite type and independent columns

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, composite-key, composite-types

Minimal definitions:

```
CREATE TYPE GlobalId AS (
  id1 BigInt,
  id2 SmallInt
);

CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id1 BigSerial NOT NULL,
  id2 SmallInt NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  global_id GlobalId NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (global_id) REFERENCES table1 (id1, id2)
);
```

In short, I use a composite type for `table2` (and many other tables), but for the primary table (`table1`), I don't directly use the composite type because composite types don't support the use of `Serial`.

The above produces the following error due to the ostensible mismatch between `global_id` and `id1, id2`: `number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree`.

Alternatively, if I define the foreign key as `FOREIGN KEY (global_id.id1, global_id.id2) REFERENCES table1 (id1, id2)`, I get a syntax error on using an accessor on `global_id`.

Any ideas on how to define this foreign key relationship? Alternatively, if there's a way for `table1` to use the `GlobalId` composite type while still getting serial/sequence behavior for `id1`, that works also.

Comment: Alternatively, I may just drop the use of composite types.

Comment: I think that would be a good course of action. You're kind of doubling up on the definition of the id1,id2 unique pair i.e. defined once explicitly as a type and then again in `table1`. I would have a redundant primary key on `table1` and reference that from `table2 etc. Traditional and boring, yes, but it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `table1` using your composite type and fill the value using a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id globalid PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE SEQUENCE s OWNED BY table1.id;

CREATE FUNCTION ins_trig() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.id = (nextval('s'), (NEW.id).id2);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE ins_trig();

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (ROW(NULL, 42));

SELECT * FROM table1;
   id   
--------
 (1,42)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I guess I'll keep going down the composite type path :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the composite type is the best solution. A `DEFAULT` value is simpler and more performant than a trigger. There is also nothing wrong with composite primary and foreign keys. But choose the composite type if it offers advantages that outweigh these drawbacks.